# How to set cookie before test in Laravel?

Tags: testing, cookies, laravel-5, phpunit

I need to test a specific behaviour based on the presence of a cookie, how do I set a cookie before sending the request (or visiting the page) ? For the moment the following fails, it behaves likes nothing was set.

```
$this->actingAs($user)
       ->withSession(['user' => $user, 'profile' => $profile]) ;
@setcookie( 'locale_lc', "fr", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 900, '/', "domain.com", true, true) ;
$this->visit('/profile') ;
```

Or

```
$cookie = ['locale_lc' => Crypt::encrypt('fr')] ;

$this->actingAs($user)
         ->withSession(['user' => $user, 'profile' => $profile])
         ->makeRequest('GET', '/profile', [], $cookie) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the setting and reading of cookies. Neither `@setcookie` nor `$_COOKIE` will work from a testing context. The method `makeRequest` with a cookie array is the right one.

However !

The reading script (controller, middleware) must be using Laravel's `$request->cookie()` method and not directly try to access it with `$_COOKIE`. In my case the cookie needs to be read by another app on our domain so I also had to disable the encryption for that specific cookie, which can be done in `EncryptCookies.php`

**EncryptCookies**

```
<?php

protected $except = [
        'locale_lc'
    ];
```

**Test**

```
<?php

$cookie = ['locale_lc' => 'fr'] ;

$this->actingAs($user)
         ->withSession(['user' => $user, 'profile' => $profile])
         ->makeRequest('GET', '/profile', [], $cookie) ;
```

**Middleware**

```
<?php

public function handle($request, Closure $next){
  if($request->cookie('locale_lc')){...}
}
```

Comment: Would this still work if you hadn't disabled the encryption?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a solution,  you can attach cookies to your test request using the withCookie method:

```
$this->withCookie('my-cookie', 'value')->get('/');
```